# C# Mouse PreMove Event?

Tags: c#, winforms, winforms-interop

Can anyone tell me if exist an event MousePreMove with an eventargs which inform me for the cursors movement direction?

I've found a Win API to block any user input but it isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for a time machine.  Store the previously known position instead.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't a `MousePreMove` event, but you can write something on your own to get the direction of the cursor. For example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    Point cursorPosition;
    Direction cursorDirection, previousCursorPosition;

    public event EventHandler<MouseDirectionEventArgs> DirectionChanged;

    public Form1( ) {
        InitializeComponent( );
        cursorPosition = PointToClient( Cursor.Position );

        DirectionChanged += new EventHandler<MouseDirectionEventArgs>( Form1_DirectionChanged );
    }

    void Form1_DirectionChanged( object sender, MouseDirectionEventArgs e ) {
        MessageBox.Show( e.MouseDirection.ToString( ) );
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove( MouseEventArgs e ) {

        if ( e.X > cursorPosition.X && e.Y > cursorPosition.Y )
            cursorDirection = Direction.RightDown;
        else if ( e.X > cursorPosition.X && e.Y < cursorPosition.Y )
            cursorDirection = Direction.RightUp;
        else if ( e.X < cursorPosition.X && e.Y > cursorPosition.Y )
            cursorDirection = Direction.LeftDown;
        else if ( e.X < cursorPosition.X && e.Y < cursorPosition.Y )
            cursorDirection = Direction.LeftUp;

        OnDirectionChanged(new MouseDirectionEventArgs( cursorDirection ) );

        previousCursorPosition = new Point(cursorPosition.X, cursorPosition.Y);
        cursorPosition = e.Location;

        base.OnMouseMove( e );
    }

    protected virtual void OnDirectionChanged(MouseDirectionEventArgs e){
        if ( DirectionChanged != null )
            DirectionChanged( this, e );
    }
}

enum Direction {
    LeftUp,
    LeftDown,
    RightUp,
    RightDown
}

class MouseDirectionEventArgs : EventArgs {
    public readonly Direction MouseDirection {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MouseDirectionEventArgs( Direction direction ) {
        MouseDirection = direction;
    }
}
```

This is a simple program that show the mouse direction compared to the previous mouse position.

**EDIT:**

If you want to prevent the mouse move in a direction you should do like here:

```
void Form1_DirectionChanged( object sender, MouseDirectionEventArgs e ) {
     if(e.MouseDirtection == Direction.LeftUp) //example
        Cursor.Position = PointToScreen( previousCursorPosition );
}
```

Comment: Ok, but my goal is to prevent mouse move event for just only direction. i can use your code in order to know which is the direction, but if some my condition has occurs, I need to prevent movement versus top, bottom, right or left. Through Cursor.Clip property I'll never be able to block movement right to left. Any idea?

Comment: I'm sorry it's not works. Through WndProc overrides I'm preventing form off screen. If the form has reached, for instance, the max width position (it means that form is docked on right of the screen) I must be able to allow all mouse movement, except for left to right direction. Have you now understand me?

Answer (score 0):

I really do not understand why you would want to stop the mouse from moving.  an important problem this will create is that your user wont beable to move the mouse (obviously).  So, when you implment this while the user is using your program they wont be able to click the Start menu for example.

However, as that is your goal you will be better served by changing your thinking from 'stop mouse moving' to 'if mouse is not where I want it, put it where I do'.

so, use a OnMouseMove event as per Fuex's code, and something like this (this is just psuedocode)

cursorPosition = e.Location;

if(cursorPosition != alowedArea)
{
    cursorPosition = preciousCursorPostion;
}

preciousCursorPostion = cursorPosition;

e.Location = cursorPosition;